# Bing Ads API PollGenerateReport Download URL says "ResourceNotFound"

Tags: soap, postman, bing-api, bing-ads-api

Kind of stuck with this. I was able to request for a report using "SubmitGenerateReport" API for GeographicalPerformanceReportRequest and it responded with a report ID. Attached the response I got from the API call using Postman.

[SubmitGenerateReport Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czLfV.png)

Attaching the API request as well.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
    <AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">tokenhere</AuthenticationToken>
    <Action mustUnderstand="1">SubmitGenerateReport</Action>
    <CustomerAccountId i:nil="false">accountID here</CustomerAccountId>
    <CustomerId i:nil="false">customerId here</CustomerId>
    <DeveloperToken i:nil="false">Developer token here</DeveloperToken>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SubmitGenerateReportRequest xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
      <ReportRequest i:nil="false" i:type="GeographicPerformanceReportRequest">
        <Format i:nil="false">Csv</Format>
        <ReportName i:nil="false">reportName1</ReportName>
        <!--These fields are applicable if the derived type attribute is set to AccountPerformanceReportRequest-->
        <Aggregation>Summary</Aggregation>
        <Columns i:nil="false">
          <GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>CampaignName</GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>
          <GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>Ctr</GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>
          <GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>Spend</GeographicPerformanceReportColumn>
        </Columns>
        <Scope i:nil="false">
          <AccountIds i:nil="false" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a1:long>accountID here</a1:long>
          </AccountIds>
        </Scope>
        <Time i:nil="false">
          <PredefinedTime i:nil="false">Last30Days</PredefinedTime>
          <ReportTimeZone i:nil="false">EasternTimeUSCanada</ReportTimeZone>
        </Time>
      </ReportRequest>
    </SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I got the download URL like the this from the PollGenerateReport API when I passed the report ID I got from SubmitGenerateReport API.

[Response from PollGenerateReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vU6lD.png)

Payload for PollGenerateReport

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
    <Action mustUnderstand="1">PollGenerateReport</Action>
    <AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">token here</AuthenticationToken>
    <CustomerAccountId i:nil="false">accountId here</CustomerAccountId>
    <CustomerId i:nil="false">customer Id here</CustomerId>
    <DeveloperToken i:nil="false">Developer token here</DeveloperToken>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <PollGenerateReportRequest xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v13">
      <ReportRequestId i:nil="false">1171543907220_1694422237806</ReportRequestId>
    </PollGenerateReportRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But, when I try to download the report using the URL provided, it says Resource not found error and throws the following.

**The specified resource does not exist**

[Download URL Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSyHX.png)

Am I missing anything? Any leads appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a same response, it may help someone in the future.

When you get ReportDownloadUrl value, you need to replace `&amp;` with `&` first. Then use the URL to download the zip file.